# Magento 1.7.02 How to redirect to other categories with html links?

Tags: php, html, magento

I have a **Magento 1.7.0.2** SHOP with **some categories** lets assume **clothes** and **shoes**

The category clothes.html has always a 3 column layout meaning 3columns.phtml.
I have placed in my 3columns.phtml file all my category links with images in this way

```
 <td style="text-align: center;">
               <p style="font-family: Open Sans, serif; font-size:17pt; font-style:bold; color:#56c1f5; "><img style="float: left; padding: 15px;" src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/shoes.png') ?>" alt="shoes"/>Shoes</p>
               <p> This is my Shoes Category <a href="shoes.html" > Go to Shoes Category </a> </p>
   </td>
```

So If I am already viewing the /eshop/clothes.html category by pressing the above link I will be redirected in eshop/shoes.html. **This works !**

**The problem is when I am viewing the clothes category after a making a search!**

Then In my URL I have also some search elements - for example
**http://demo.demomagento.nl/index.php/catalogsearch/result/?q=shoes**

**If I press to redirect to shoes.html it will not find the page because
it will embedd the existist search url with the "shoes.html"**

http://demo.demomagento.nl/index.php/catalogsearch/result/shoes.html 
  **Which ofcourse does not exist!**

I think the problem is at the links that I pasted as HTML in 3pagelayout which are like

```
 <a href="shoes.html" >
```

But how can I solve this ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This link format should solve your issue:

```
<a href="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('', array('_direct'=>'shoes.html'))?>">See Some Shoes Dude</a>
```

I didn't exactly understand why are you having a `eshop` in your url. In case the code above doesn't work try this:

```
<a href="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('', array('_direct'=>'eshop/shoes.html'))?>">See Some Shoes Dude</a>
```

Comment: Thank you Marius (again)...I will try it and I will return! The word eshop is something I put on SO in order not to reveal the real name project that I am working. Give me some time I am new in Magento!

Comment: You are my magento savior man!It works like a charm...I think Magento has a lot of depth comparing with the rest of eshop and cms.This is my feeling